# Sequential Hölder-norm for functions in $H_{\alpha}([0,1]^{d})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis

I have come across a nice result attributed to Ciesielski (Ciesielski, Z. (1960). On the isomorphisms of the spaces $H_{\alpha}$ and m. Bull. Acad. Pol. Sci. Ser. Sci. Math. Phys. 8, 217–222.), even if I can't find the original paper. It gives a sequential equivalent of $\alpha$-Hölder-norm for any function $f$ in $H_{\alpha}([0,1])$, defined by,
\begin{aligned}
\|f\|_\alpha^{seq}:=\sup _{j \geqslant 1} 2^{j \alpha} \max _{1 \leqslant k \leqslant 2^{j-1}} \mid f\left((2 k) 2^{-j}\right) & -2 f\left((2 k-1) 2^{-j}\right)+f\left((2 k-2) 2^{-j}\right)|+| f(0)|+|f(1)|
\end{aligned}
This is pretty handy to study some stochastic processes (such as Brownian Motion). As I am looking at random fields, I wonder if, somehow, somewhere, this result has been generalized for functions in  $H_{\alpha}([0,1]^{d})$, $d>1$ ?

Comment: The article I am currently reading states that $\|f\|_{\alpha}^{seq}$ is equivalent to $$\|f\|_{\alpha}=|f(0)|+|f(1)|+\sup _{\substack{s, t \in[0,1]}} \frac{|x(t)-x(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}$$

Comment: This is exactly this idea of discretized increments that I find attractive, but I don't know if it can be generalized well in higher dimensions than 1.

Comment: I think that this article : http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~suquet/Articles/georgia1.pdf answer my question, thank you.

Comment: isn’t the generalisation to higher dimension immediate if you apply the 1 estimate to each variable?